# PHP: Upload more files

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

please help me with my PHP upload problem:

My code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['uploadsubmit'])) {
  for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
   if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./images/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
   }
  }
 }
?> 

<form action="#" method="post" name="uploadimg"> 
<input type="file" name="upload[]" /><br />
<input type="file" name="upload[]" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="uploadsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my problem is:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: upload in
>   C:\web\php_structure\type\article.php on line 71

line 71:

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
```

and upload is not executed.
Upload in php.ini is **On**

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form element?

Comment: Ian Drake: Very thanks, im dummy :-D

Comment: You're welcome. File uploads are tricky. Also note that it's generally considered bad practice (from a performance standpoint), to do your `count()` function as part of the `for` loop, because it executes on every iteration. Do it once above the loop and save it to a variable. Don't forget, you can use a `foreach` loop here too.

Comment: thank you, can you please advise how to apply here foreach

Comment: Replace your current `for` line with `foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $i => $fileName)`. I prefer `foreach` over `for` when iterating over arrays because I feel like it reduces the chance of an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: OK, and body of the loop is the same? Or I must apply '$fileName'

Comment: Yep, body of the loop should be the exact same (obviously I can't execute all of your code to test). You can ignore `$fileName` if you don't need it. Your reference to the array index `$i` will keep working fine. I would definitely recommend you [read about foreach loops in the official PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). There is also some good documentation about [uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Comment: ok, thank you very much, I can last question ... How to find out the $ _FILES empty? (no file is recorded) thanks

Comment: You mean like [this kind of empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)? The official documentation is your best friend when working with PHP. You will become more self-sufficient if you refer to that first. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365315/php-image-upload/49365498#49365498